# ¿Cómo esperar [x] segundos antes de actualizar un componente visual en WPF? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, interfaz-gráfica, ui

En WPF, intento de que al llamar a un método Encender(), un textbox muestre el mensaje "ENCENDIENDO" por 2 segundos, y recién pasado este tiempo, el mismo textbox muestre otro mensaje. Para lograrlo, intenté detener todo a través del método Sleep de Thread justo después de mostrar el mensaje "ENCENDIENDO" y luego cambiar el texto, sin embargo, al probar, el textbox jamás muestra el mensaje "ENCENDIENDO", a pesar de que en depuración pude comprobar que la propiedad Text del textbox se asignara correctamente. Simplemente pasaron los dos segundos sin mostrar nada, y luego mostró únicamente el texto siguiente (en este caso: "Listo para operar").

```
private void Encender()
{
   txtbx_Principal.Text = "ENCENDIENDO";
   Thread.Sleep(2000);
   txtbx_Principal.Text = "Listo para operar";
}
```

Intenté también utilizando this.UpdateLayout() justo después de la primera instrucción, pero no dio resultado. Según investigué, esto ocurre por un tema de priorización de la plataforma, que deja la carga de elementos visuales para el final, pero la verdad es que quedo igual de perdido respecto al cómo solucionarlo. Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Thread.Sleep(de System.Threading)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=net-7.0) bloquea el hilo actual de ejecución y, con esto, bloquea la UI.

Te sugiero emplear un método asincrónico `async` en conjunto con una espera `await` a [`Task.Delay(de System.Threading.Tasks)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-7.0) que hace al código esperar sin bloquear la UI, pues no bloquea el hilo actual de ejecución.

De esta forma:

```
private async void Encender()
{
   txtbx_Principal.Text = "ENCENDIENDO";
   await Task.Delay(2000);
   txtbx_Principal.Text = "Listo para operar";
}
```

[Esta entrada de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep) ofrece más detalles sobre esto.